# Parsing data onto google map

Tags: json, google-maps, parsing, google-maps-api-3, coordinates

I am trying to parse the latitude and longitude from a json file onto Google map, as well as several other data into the information window. However i think might have screw up somewhere as when i tried to run the file, all i got was a blank screen. Can someone point out what i have done wrong. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

I have made use of the earthquake data created by google as my reference point.

```
>   window.eqfeed_callback = function(results) {
      var bounds=new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      for (var i = 0; i < results.features.length; i++) {

        var accesspoint = results.features[i]; 
        var latitude = accesspoint.3.WifiLatitude;
        var longtitude = accesspoint.4.WifiLongtitude;      

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude &&longtitude); 
        bounds.extend(latLng);
        var content ="<div style='height:100px; width:300px; overflow:auto;'><table>";
    content += "<tr><th align='left'>id</th><td>"+accesspoint.id+"</td></tr>";
    content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiMacAddress</th><td>"+accesspoint.4.WifiMacAddress+"</td></tr>";
    content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiSSID</th><td>"+accesspoint.4.WifiSSID+"</td></tr>";
    content += "<tr><th align='left'>WifiFrequency</th><td>"+accesspoint.4.WifiFrequency+"</td></tr>";
    content += "<tr><th align='left'>SignalStrength</th><td>"+accesspoint.4.SignalStrength+"</td></tr>";
    content +="</table>";
    createMarker(latLng,earthquake.id,content);
```

the json file i have been trying to parse data out

```
   {"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":["21-00-00-00-00-00"],"WifiSSID":"Edurom","WifiLatitude":[-27.501008],"WifiLongtitude":[153.011720],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"},

"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":["21-00-00-00-00-00"],"WifiSSID":"Edurom","WifiLatitude":[-27.501541],"WifiLongtitude":[153.005755],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"},

"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":["21-00-00-00-00-00"],"WifiSSID":"Edurom","WifiLatitude":[-27.499142],"WifiLongtitude":[153.008845],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"},

"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":["21-00-00-00-00-00"],"WifiSSID":"Edurom","WifiLatitude":[-27.498000],"WifiLongtitude":[153.015153],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"},

"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":["21-00-00-00-00-00"],"WifiSSID":"Edurom","WifiLatitude":[-27.495069],"WifiLongtitude":[153.011549],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

a [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes two numbers as its arguments.  This is not correct:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude &&longtitude);
```

should be

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude , longtitude);
```

and safer to be:

```
var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longtitude));
```

as coming from JSON, they are both strings.  You could even verify they are valid numbers, by testing "isNaN" before using them to construct the google.maps.LatLng.

Comment: i have made various changes base on your suggestion. The map is finally back though the market is not plotting. To simplify the whole testing process, i have cut down the json file to just a one portion instead. 

`var wifin = results.features[i]; 
        var latitude = wifin.WifiLatitude;
  var longtitude = wifin.WifiLongtitude;  

        var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(latitude), parseFloat(longtitude));
        bounds.extend(latLng);
map.fitBounds(bounds);
    }`

Comment: the json file looks like this

`{"wifin":{"WifiMacAddress":21-00-00-00-00-00","WifiSSID":BigPond213131,"WifiLatitude":[-27.501008],"WifiLongtitude":[153.011720],"WifiFrequency":"80","SignalStrength":"60"}}`

Comment: What does your createMarker function look like? What javascript errors are you getting?  Can you provide a jsfiddle (or a link to a live map) that exhibits the problem?

Comment: `function createMarker(latLng, title, content) {
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: latLng,
          map: map,
          title: title
        });`
I was mistaken. There is a java error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` pointing to my json file.

Comment: You would be better off adding the createMarker function to your question (so it can be formatted in a way that makes it easier to read) rather than putting it in the comments.  The (javascript not java) error means that your JSON isn't valid, you need to fix that before it will load and display markers.

Comment: I see. ALright so i have validated my Json file and this are the javascript errors i have got.

`Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/Hgo13k-tfSpn0qi1SFdUfT8E0i7KZn-EPnyo3HZu7kw.woff".
Resource interpreted as Font but transferred with MIME type font/woff: "https://themes.googleusercontent.com/static/fonts/roboto/v9/2UX7WLTfW3W8TclTUvlFyQ.woff"`

Comment: Pardon me. There is still a Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token : pointing to my json file even when my file went through validation.

Comment: Is this the snippet you posted in your question that has the error or a more comprehensive file that we can't see?

Comment: I have edited the whole json file into the question. It is pretty much the same as the one i have uploaded previously

Comment: How are you loading the JSON?

Comment: i am loading it via pointing the source at the directory .

`var script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = 'C:/Users/user/Dropbox/Sem2_Study/testJSON.json';`

Comment: How are you accessing it once you load it. The snippet you posted doesn't assign it to anything.  And the code you posted to parse it expects it to have a features array at the top level.

Comment: I am running it via my html file with the codings embedded. So basically there is only 2 files involved. 1) html 2)json. The html file is where all the codes are stored. **Also i have removed the feature array as you have pointed out.