# Creating Google Maps LatLng classes dynamically

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create markers on a google map using google's own API. My issue is that I'm reading JSON data from a text file then trying to break it down to the latitudes and longitudes so I can place markers on the map. You can see my code below.

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest(); //New request object
oReq.onload = function() {
//This is where you handle what to do with the response.
//The actual data is found on this.responseText
//alert(this.responseText); //Will alert: the location latitude and longitude in JSON

locations = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
//alert(locations);
for(var i = 0; i < locations.length; i++ ){
    var tempLocation = locations[i];
    //alert(tempLocation);

    var tempLat = tempLocation.latitude;
    var tempLong = tempLocation.longitude;
    tempLat = tempLat.toString();
    tempLong = tempLong.toString();

    pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(tempLat + ", " + tempLong);  
}
    var tempPictureLocation = pictureLocations.toString();
    alert(tempPictureLocation);

};
```

My issue is that the variable pictureLocations returns NaN. I believe that their is something wrong with my constructing statement but not sure exactly what's wrong. If I hardcode in some coordinates it also doesn't work. Thanks for the help!

Comment: try adding a console.log() statement after you get your lat long values from the file and see what they are as they get passed to LatLng function.

Comment: A [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) object takes two numbers as arguments, not a string containing two numeric strings separated by a comma...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parsing data onto google map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18464174/parsing-data-onto-google-map/18466611#18466611)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a [google.maps.LatLng object](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng) takes **two numbers** as its arguments.  This is not correct:

```
pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(tempLat + ", " + tempLong);
```

should be

```
pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(tempLat,tempLong);
```

and safer to be:

```
pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(
                            parseFloat(tempLocation.latitude),
                            parseFloat(tempLocation.longitude));
```

as coming from JSON, they are both strings.  You could even verify they are valid numbers, by testing "isNaN" before using them to construct the google.maps.LatLng.

Answer (score 0):

`pictureLocations`, the way you are using it is an array ... to output as a string, try ...

```
var tempPictureLocation = pictureLocations.join(" ");
```

Although, this may not work as I am not sure what ...

```
pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(tempLat + ", " + tempLong);
```

... is dropped into the array with this code.

Comment: Thanks for the help I just solved it. I don't need the comma in quotes.

Comment: I probably would have missed that, but it makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps LatLng constructor is designed for the arguement to have a comma between the numbers so it looks like this: `pictureLocations[i] = new google.maps.LatLng(tempLat, tempLong);`